# $A$ , $B$ are real matrices such that $AB－BA$ is nilpotent , does it follow that $\det(A^2＋B^2)≥0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are exchangable real matrices then $\det(A^2＋B^2)≥0$. What if $AB－BA$ is nilpotent ?
Thanks for all help